# Code based file download

Tags: php, web, download

Are there any good open, premade libraries or other systems for a file download based on unique codes distributed to the user?

The idea here is to generate a set of codes, that lets each user use his code to download a file. Preferably with a customizable limit to times downloaded and/or time limit.

if not, good ideas on how to implement this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generating those codes, you can use a function that generates a random string or simply the PHP's native rand() function. Then you create a table in the db that features the code you generated and the location of the file associated with it.

The download.php file should be called like this : download.php?hash=generated_code

And look like this:

```
<?php
// Retrieve filename and file location on the disk from the db
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$sql_response['filename']);
readfile($sql_response['filelocationondisk']);
?>
```

Also you can restrict download limits using cookies or counting the amount downloaded by IP in the database.